# Pass OutArgument value of one activity to InArgument of another activity?

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

Is there a way to pass OutArgument value of one activity to InArgument of another activity?  Or a local variable can be created automatically in root activity container base on the OutArguments of dragged activities during **design** time, which can be used to automatically backup the value of OutArgument using extension?

I know its looks impossible in WF4 using standard way. But is there some wild way can do this? Or simulate the way like WF3?

Please post any of your thought.

Thanks

Yadong

Comment: If you want to pass a variable from one activity to the immediately after, maybe you should consider joining both of them in one single activity. Anyway, check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an already filled workflow at design time with all your variables and activities, maybe you can workout something with [IActivityTemplateFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.iactivitytemplatefactory.aspx).

```
public class TwoActivitiesBundle : IActivityTemplateFactory
{
    public Activity Create(DependencyObject target)
    {
        return new Sequence
        {
            Variables =
            {
                new Variable<int>("addResult"),
            },

            Activities =
            {
                new Add<int, int, int>
                {
                    Left = 10,
                    Right = 10,
                    Result = new VisualBasicReference<int>("addResult")
                },

                new WriteLine { Text = "Now I'll use 'addResult', as a value on the next activity" },

                new Subtract<int, int, int>
                {
                    Left = new VisualBasicValue<int>("addResult"),
                    Right = 10,
                },

                new WriteLine { Text = new VisualBasicValue<string>("\"Print addResultValue: \" & addResult")}
            }
        };
    }
}
```

In short, *IActivityTemplateFactory* allows you to drop already build and filled activities to the designer. Then you add your factory, in this case *TwoActivitiesBundle*, to the designer's toolbox, as any other activity:

```
new ToolboxItemWrapper(typeof(TwoActivitiesBundle), null, "My Bundle");
```

---

**Extra:**

If you really want to add variables to the parent container you can use the `target` parameter received on `Create()` method to traverse the workflow and find such container.

This is an example that assumes that you drop `TwoActivitiesBundle` inside a Sequence and adds a variable to the latter:

```
public class TwoActivitiesBundle : IActivityTemplateFactory
{
    public Activity Create(DependencyObject target)
    {
        var sequenceModelItem = (target as WorkflowViewElement).ModelItem;

        sequenceModelItem
            .Properties["Variables"]
            .Collection
            .Add(new Variable<string>("myFirstDesignTimeVariable", "var text here"));


        // This activity writes "I've just created a new variable: var text here" to the console

        return new WriteLine
        {
            Text = new VisualBasicValue<string>("\"I've just created a new variable: \" & myFirstDesignTimeVariable");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.model.modelitem.aspx), ModelItem *represents a single item in the editing model*. Being so you can traverse the all workflow using [Root](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.model.modelitem.root.aspx), [Parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.model.modelitem.parent.aspx) and [Parents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.model.modelitem.parents.aspx) properties. Then you can edit each ModelItem properties just like I show you on the example above. Note that this is quite laborious and may require you to take several assumptions along the way.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, U do show me a good idea, and will save me a lot of time.